# Iterator Segfault with List class in C++

Tags: c++, string, list, hashtable

I am working on a project for one of my comp sci classes that uses Hash Tables to sort strings into a vector of linked lists from STL's List Class. When inserting a string into the list, all indexes except for an index of 3 always result in a SEGFAULT error. I have no idea why this is occurring. Here is the code for the insertion function along with a few examples of the error I am receiving. The vector "table" is declared to hold 4 elements in the default constructor

```
void Stringset::insert(string word)
{
    cout << "insertion" << endl;
    hash<string> stringHash;
    int hashIndex = stringHash(word) % size;
    cout << hashIndex << endl;
    bool exists = false;
    //find intended index and create base boolean variable for whether or not the value already exists
    list<string>::iterator pos = table[hashIndex].begin();
    list<string>::iterator end = table[hashIndex].end();
    for(pos; pos != end; pos++){
        cout << "pass" << endl;
        if((*pos).compare(word) == 0){
            exists = true;
        }
    }
    if(!exists){
        table[hashIndex].push_back(word);
        num_elems++;
        cout << "inserted " << (*pos) << endl;
    }
    else{

    }
}
```

Here are a few examples of the SEGFAULT occuring along with the cases of insertion with a  of 3 working:

```
I: insert word
F: find word
R: remove word
P: print words in stringset
Q: quit
I
Enter word to insert: By
insertion
3
inserted 
I: insert word
F: find word
R: remove word
P: print words in stringset
Q: quit
I
Enter word to insert: Try
insertion
3
pass
inserted 
I: insert word
F: find word
R: remove word
P: print words in stringset
Q: quit
I
Enter word to insert: Error
insertion
2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Along with a singular case:

```
I: insert word
F: find word
R: remove word
P: print words in stringset
Q: quit
I
Enter word to insert: Error
insertion
2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Stringset.h as well as the Stringset objects default constructor:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

//Stringset class, do not modify definitions for existing members
class Stringset
{
    private:
        vector<list<string>> table;
        int num_elems;
        int size;
    public:
        Stringset();
        vector<list<string>> getTable() const;
        int getNumElems() const;
        int getSize() const;
        void insert(string word);
        bool find(string word) const;
        void remove(string word);
};

Stringset::Stringset() : table(4), num_elems(0), size(4) {}
```

I am fairly certain that it is always crashing once the program hits the for loop but I am not sure why due to my unfamiliarity with iterators. Any ideas as to how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is `table` defined and populated, and what is `size` set to in relation to `table`? Why not use `table.size()` instead?

Comment: Can you show your constructor? more specifically, can you show how `table` is initialized? Do you create a list object for all indizes of the table vector? Your examples suggest that only the last entry is initialized correctly while the other entries are either unitialized or null. I suspect your error is in your constructor

Comment: tangent: `cout << "inserted " << (*pos) << endl;` as written dereferences an end iterator. You probably meant to write `word` instead of `*pos`. You can `break` out of your search loop once you find a matching word.

Comment: @John "*You can `break` out of your search loop once you find a matching word*'- or, even better, consider using `std::find_if()` instead of a manual loop: `if (find_if(table[hashIndex].begin(), table[hashIndex].end(), [&](string &s){ return s.compare(word) == 0; }) == table[hashIndex].end()) { ... }`

Comment: @Remy stop editing your comment so I don't have to keep re-upvoting it.

Comment: Can `hashString(word) % size` return a negative value? You declare `size` as an int. You should use size_t or unsigned for your index lookups.

Answer (score 0):

I'd double check hashIndex calculation. It may cause the SEGFAULT. Also you may use some c++ syntax to save you for some headache. Take a look of the changes bellow:

```
//list<string>::iterator pos = table[hashIndex].begin();
//list<string>::iterator end = table[hashIndex].end();
bool exists = false;
for (auto& Pos : table[hashIndex]) {
    cout << "pass" << endl;
    if (Pos.compare(word) == 0) {
       exists = true;
       break;
    }
}
if (!exists) {
   table[hashIndex].push_back(word);
   num_elems++;
   //cout << "inserted " << (*pos) << endl;   
   //Pos was pointing to the .end() in your coude
   cout << "inserted " << table[hashIndex].back() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is basically correct.

The error is in your `cout << "insert" ...` line.
As was already pointed out in the comments `(*pos)` points to `endl` when you get to that code line, which is "beyond" the list. That means it's not pointing to a valid object anymore. This results in a segfault.

If I comment out that line it works for me.

ps - my suspicion in my comment above was wrong. your constructor is correct :-)